# How can I avoid inline styles with React?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, css-variables

The code written below works correctly, but I was told to re-do the code in order to avoid inline styles.

```
export default class ProductDetail extends Component {
  
  makeStyle(name, value) {
      return {
          backgroundColor: name === 'Color' ? value : "#1D1F22",
      }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className='sizesWrapper'>
        {size.items.map(item => (
          <div
            key={item.value}
            style={this.makeStyle(size.name, item.value)}
            className="productSize"
          >
            {size.name !== 'Color' && item.value}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

how can I use CSS to change the backgroud-color of each iteration of item in items array instead of using:

```
style={this.makeStyle(size.name, item.value)}
```

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)?

Comment: From your comment below I get the impression that your question is not as simple as you've presented it here. Please revise to be more clear and explain your overall strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSS file and import it in your JS file. It will apply the CSS to your component

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already have a css file imported, I just wanted to know how to have different background-color for each element in items array to display it instead of  
    style={this.makeStyle(size.name, item.value)}

Comment: You should revise your post to be more clear. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS-IN-JS, for example Styled Components.
Your code isn't complete, hence I provide you a code version to get an idea:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Div = styled.div`
...HERE INSERT YOUR STATIC CSS RULES
background-color: ${props => props.name === 'Color' ? props.value : "#1D1F22";
`;

export default class ProductDetail extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className='sizesWrapper'>
        {size.items.map(item => (
          <Div
            key={item.value}
            name={size.name}
            value={item.value}
            className="productSize"
          >
            {size.name !== 'Color' && item.value}
          </Div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Styled Components are an external library (i.e. isn't installed with create-react-app out of the box) thus you have to install with:

`npm i --save styled-components`

Here the documentation of Styled Components: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#motivation